# how to consume soap web service in C# ,ERROR 500 on response

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am consuming a web service with http and it is soap based service , on response it gives error
with http code 500 . any idea why so?

```
soap body is as
```

queryNameAvailability request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:uri="uri:v2.external.query.name.availability.asic.gov.au" xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:uri1="uri:business.document.header.types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:uri2="uri:fss.types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:uri3="uri:types.asic.gov.au" xmlns:uri4="uri:nni.types.asic.gov.au">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <uri:request>
         <uri1:businessDocumentHeader>
            <uri1:messageType>queryNameAvailability</uri1:messageType>
            <uri1:messageReferenceNumber>cnr 1</uri1:messageReferenceNumber>
            <uri1:messageVersion>2</uri1:messageVersion>
            <uri1:senderId>234</uri1:senderId>
            <uri1:senderType>REGA</uri1:senderType>
         </uri1:businessDocumentHeader>
         <uri:businessDocumentBody>
            <uri4:proposedName>CNR</uri4:proposedName>
            <uri4:companyNameAvailabilityCheck>true</uri4:companyNameAvailabilityCheck>
         </uri:businessDocumentBody>
      </uri:request>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

queryNameAvailability
            cnr 1
            3e9527dc-71fa-4103-bbb3-eb8d4221573a
            2
            ASIC
            GOVT
            
               ASIC
               Business Names
               1
            
            
               
                  2014-12-19T09:08:03
                  ASIC
               
            
            
               true
            
         
         
            Available
            CNR is available.

C# code is as

```
String user = "username";
string pwd = "password";       
NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader((Server.MapPath("").ToString() + "\\XMLFile1.xml").ToString().Replace("Home\\",""));
string soap = reader.ReadToEnd();
byte[] bytess = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(soap); 
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.gateway.uat.asic.gov.au/gateway/ExternalQueryNameAvailabilityPortV2?WSDL");
request.Credentials = creds;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
request.ContentLength = bytess.Length;
Stream oss = request.GetRequestStream();
oss.Write(bytess, 0, bytess.Length);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

on response the server error founds with code 500

Any Idea what is the reason of error ?

Comment: [from wiki:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) HTTP ERROR 500: `"A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling service , the url should not include the '?WSDL' at the end as it is only to check the detail of the service